# Return entire array with slice function

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, slice

I have a `numpy` array `arr = np.arange(20).reshape(2,10)`. I want to define a slice `sli = slice(start,stop, step)` and then later access `arr[0,sli]`. How can I define `sli` such that `arr[0,sli]` is the entire array? I.e. `sli=:`

I tried already:

```
sli = slice(0,-1) # equivalent to arr[0,:-1]
sli = slice(0,0) # equivalent to []
sli = slice(0) # equivalent to []
sli = slice(0,10) # works fine, but i might not know the shape of arr
                  # at the time I define sli
```

Comment: Have you tried `slice(None)` ?

Comment: @JonClements This works, thanks. However, is there a reason why you made it a comment and not an answer?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I know many ways how to acces the entire array, but I want one that allows to access the entire array with a variable, my program relies on a predefined variable ant then callin `arr[0,sli]`

Comment: @JürgMerlinSpaak not enough coffee, on mobile and wasn't 100% sure :) Plus - there's probably a dupe somewhere.

Comment: Uh, I thought you wanted `arr[0, slice(None)]`. If not, the ellipsis notation works:

Comment: @JonClements Yes I thought so aswell, but couldn't find the dupe

Comment: If someone wants to answer or self-answer if no dupe can be found. Fine by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Ellipsis` notation:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(20).reshape(2,10)
sli = ...
out = arr[0, sli]

print(out)    
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Works on python3.x. For older versions, you should use `slice(None)`.

Comment: Interesting, why does using the `Ellipisis` work and why would you use it? I recall omitting the arguments for a slice produces identical CPython bytecode to using `None`, so that seems like the obvious Pythonic choice?

Comment: @Chris_Rands be careful with None because it increases the dimensions in some cases.

Comment: Thanks, can you give a small example?

Comment: @Chris_Rands If you print `arr[0, None]`, it adds an extra dimension.

Answer (score 1):

By comment of JonClements

```
sli = slice(None)
arr[0,sli]
# array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

Comment: This doesn't return the whole array? Only the first row. Is that what you want?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I want a variable `sli`, s.t. `arr[0,sli]` is equivalent to `arr[0,:]`, respectively equivalent to `arr[0]`. So this works fine, unless there's some hideat.

Comment: `sli = ...; arr[0, sli]` Works my dude.

Comment: The ellipsis is around 100 nanoseconds faster (tested on arr of size (60000, 50)), that's the only diff, because it is a language construct, not a function call.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes, I know, that's why I upvoted your post. However it only works, when I want only one variable to index (respectively the last is an elipsis). Which is not the case (I know, this is not mentioned in the question, sorry for that, didn't think of such a problem at the time asking the question).

Comment: The last doesn't need to be an ellipsis. For example, `a[:, ..., 0]`.